# Building main-build.js within Durandal Application

Tags: javascript, .net, durandal, single-page-application

How can I build the `main-build.js` file within a Durandal application? Here is the file that I am referring to:

```
exports.config = function(weyland) {
    weyland.build('main')
        .task.jshint({
            include:'App/**/*.js'
        })
        .task.uglifyjs({
            include:['App/**/*.js', 'Scripts/durandal/**/*.js']
        })
        .task.rjs({
            include:['App/**/*.{js,html}', 'Scripts/durandal/**/*.js'],
            loaderPluginExtensionMaps:{
                '.html':'text'
            },
            rjs:{
                name:'../Scripts/almond-custom', //to deploy with require.js, use the build's name here instead
                insertRequire:['main'], //not needed for require
                baseUrl : 'App',
                wrap:true, //not needed for require
                paths : {
                    'text': '../Scripts/text',
                    'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
                    'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
                    'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
                    'knockout': 'empty:',
                    'bootstrap': 'empty:',
                    'jquery': 'empty:'
                },
                inlineText: true,
                optimize : 'none',
                pragmas: {
                    build: true
                },
                stubModules : ['text'],
                keepBuildDir: true,
                out:'App/main-built.js'
            }
        });
}
```

I already looked at [this](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Weyland.html) page (Building with Weyland), but it is insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `node.js`, then install the weyland npm module globally. To build the `main-build.js` file, you navigate to the root directory of your project and run `weyland` and the command prompt (this assumes your `weyland-build.js` file is in the same folder).